# C++ Finding number of characters in each word of a text file

Tags: c++, loops

I'm trying to write a C++ program where the number of characters in each word individually (not just the sum of all characters overall) of a text file is counted. I'm having trouble defining in my loop exactly when a word begins and ends (using characters). How can I reword this loop so that it recognizes a word and adds the number of characters in it to the variable called "word?" Here's what I have so far:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;
    int main(){
    ifstream fin("file.txt");
    int word=0;
    char ch;
    while(fin && ch!= '.'){
    if(ch==' ' || ch=='\n')
    word++;
```

It is wrong because some of the text may have large portions of blank spaces which, by this loop, would be counted as chars in a word. Thank you for any and all help!

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the normal input operator `>>` skips white-space.

That means you can read into a `std::string` object and increase the counter for each such "word".

Answer (score 0):

You could also only increase the word length if the current character in your loop is a letter by using `isalpha(ch);`

***Example 01:***

```
#include <string>

using std::string;

string Sentence = "I'm trying to write a C++ program where the number of characters in each word individually (not just the sum of all characters overall) of a text file is counted.";

int main() {

    unsigned WordLength(0);

    for (auto i = Sentence.begin(); i != Sentence.end(); ++i) {
        if (isalpha(*i))
            ++WordLength;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Of course you would have to decide if you want to count the +'es in C++ or the `'` character as part of the word, or alternatively add logic to ignore those characters. You could also use `isspace(ch)`. Only counting up if the letter is not a space. But then you need to make sure you ignore punctuation etc. Which you could do using `ispunct(ch)`. But you'd still need logic to take care of special cases like `'` or `'+'` or other characters you might want to count or not count :D

***Example 02:***

```
unsigned WordLength(0);

for (auto i = Sentence.begin(); i != Sentence.end(); ++i) {
    if (isspace(*i) || ispunct(*i)) {
        /// Print length of word then reset
        WordLength = 0;
    }
    else {
        ++WordLength;
    }
}
```

Anyway, hope it helps! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string temp;
    int word=0;
    ifstream inf("new.txt");
    while(inf.good()){
        inf>>temp;
        if(inf.eof())
            break;
        word+=temp.length();
    }
    cout<<word;
    return 0;
}
```

The text file will be read word by word and copied to 'temp' string. If you just count the alphabets of all words then you just have to count the string.
For other operations(for any or some particular alphabets), you can check the 'temp' string.